# Can I remotely force archiving on Lotus Notes clients?

Tags: lotus-notes

My organization has about 1,000 lotus notes email clients.  Right now we are running into a space issue.  Obviously it would be easy to buy more disk space, but I was wondering if there was a way to force all the clients remotely to force archive email?

Comment: This question is probably better answered on our sister site Serverfault. K to the Z, we're voting to move it there automatically. Don't post a new copy of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, setup an archiving policy and deploy to your users. You may need to deploy repeatedly on any Notes clients that are less than version 8 (which began to prevent overriding of policies)

You should be able find the details in the Admin help pages. Failing that here's a copy on IBM's website: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_CREATING_AN_ARCHIVE_SUBPOLICY_STEPS.html

You've got two approaches in terms of archiving. Either delete messages older than the criteria or move those messages on an archive (which is a glorified copy of the users' mail file folder structure.

The latter require a bit of work. You've got to provision a dedicated archive server with a bit of disk space, then give everyone permissions equivalent to those you would for a mail user on said server.

Don't forget to have a program document that actually does the archiving (preferrably out of hours, but not conflicting with existing maintenance tasks (don't forget to run "show configuartion servertask*" to see what tasks run out of hours). Confusingly enough this is handled by the compact task. Use the -a switch so it archives and then compacts otherwise you'll see no disk space recovery.

If you're using Notes/Domino 8.5 I'd also recommend enabling DAOS (single instancing of attachments) as this could mitigate future storage problems.